# getting partial object from three tables Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I have three tables User, UserRole(Join table) and Role. From the role table i need to get the name on a condition base. I have sql query which is working on this scenario but want to try on using criteria.

```
Select firstname, lastname from user, userrole, role where user.id=userrole.userid and userrole.roleid=role.id and role.name='James';
```

This returning the partial objects firstname and lastname which i can use later with as fullname.

How can i do the same thing with either HQL or Criteria?Can any one help me?

in my user Entity

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)    
@JoinTable(
        name = "userrole",
        joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "userid") },
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "roleid")
)
public Set<Role> getRoles() {
    return roles;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Code as Given below.

```
Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
Query query = session.createQuery("from user user where user.name=:username").setParameter("username", "James");
List<User> list = query.list();
```